# Meaning of "turn-around"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

When daylight came on the morning after the shooting, blood could be
seen on the sea pebbles of the **turn-around** in front of the house. Two petrol
tins were found behind a tree.

Does it mean: a place like a half of the circle in front of the house?

Source: The Story Of Lucy Gault by William Trevor

Answer (score 1):

Most houses have a drive... a road leading to the front door or to a garage. Cars can drive in, but have to reverse out.

[image]

Large houses often have a roundabout in front of the main entrance so that, when the owners have a party, cars can enter on one side, drop off guests in front of the entrance, then drive out of the other side. This can be called a turn-around.

[image]